# Lock device with Ionic Framework

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to find a solution to lock my device with Ionic Framework. I know you can do it with Android Native, but I can't find a solution for my Ionic project.

Any solution or package I could use for that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

**cordova-plugin-screen-locker** to lock the device screen

Comment: I'm can't make it work for Ionic. My project doesn't find the plugin.

Comment: @OriolLopez What version of Ionic are you working with?